# How does one become a Lantern (kind of)

Tags: dc, batman, video-games, green-lantern

OK, so recently I've been playing Lego Batman 3: Beyond Gotham, and yes I know that Lego games aren't always perfect in maintaining cannon but they are usually pretty good so if this is completely counteracted by cannon, I'm sorry.

So anyway, when I was playing Lego Batman, on one of the levels you must fight Indigo-1 because the indigo lantern power battery was broken thus her compassion was completely lacking when she was talking to Batman and Co.

So my question is a complicatedly simple one, first off, without the lantern's aid is Indigo-1 completely compassion-less, and second, how does one become a member of the lantern corps of a particular color if they are lacking in that attribute? And if the answer to the first question is no, I am still interested in how one becomes part of the lantern corps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll stay simple..

there are 3 main things to consider:

1- Its the ring that choses its bearer.

2- The proximity; when a lantern dies the ring then chose a new bearer.

3- The selection is done by carefully selecting the individual that is filled naturally by what emotion the ring is looking for. The ring then gives its power to the new bearer by increasing the new bearer's natural basic emotion.

Comment: To support the proximity claim, when Abin Sur was dying the ring found 2 viable candidates: Guy Gardner and Hal Jordan. Hal Jordan was physically closer to Abin Sur's crash site, and so he was chosen instead of Guy Gardner. http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_%28Guy_Gardner%29 See the "Green Lantern Corps" section, 2nd sentence.

Comment: @CreationEdge excellent supportive comment thanks a lot :D

Comment: So in the case of Indigo-1 in my Lego Batman game, why was she being so uncompassionate if she would have had to be compassionate in order to be selected as an indigo lantern? Here's a link to the level where this happens, I played it on the 3ds but the story is still the same: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9X1SQovnLYk.

Comment: @Cyberson When she is freed from her ring, she initially reverts to her old, violent personality; however, because of the previous influence of the Indigo power of compassion, she comes to regret her actions, and begs to have her ring and status returned. source to learn about her *old violent personality* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_Tribe#Indigo-1

Comment: If you read further in that page, you'll see that the Indigo rings force the wearers to feel compassion only, and give you the power to feel compassion or the lack thereof in others. So, this ring may seek out individuals who *lack* compassion, because it forces them to have it. Those who are already compassionate don't benefit as much from the forced compassion.